# How to add a link for a popup window when user selects a particular variation

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using PopupMaker plugin for wordpress to create the popup up.  This works by using a click trigger on a css selector of your choosing.

With this line of code I can output the variations for the particular product when I'm on its single product page.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'dump_attributes' );

function dump_attributes() {
  global $product;
  var_dump($product->get_attribute('size'));
 }
```

I need to output a click-able link only when the customer selects a certain variation from the drop down.

The problem I have is generating that link only when a user selects the variation 'Drum'.

[image]

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#size, #pa_size').change(function(){
    $selection = $(this).val();
    console.log($selection);
  $(this).after(
    '<div>' +
    ($selection == 'Drum' ? '<a href="#"><div id="add">Freight Restrictions</div></a>' : '')  +
    '</div>'
  );
 })
});`

Comment: I figured out this code to do somewhat of what I wanted, but then the link doesn't go away if the user selects a different option. Also the link duplicates if the user re-selects the 'drum' item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to give this a little more thought. First, we need to give the variation data that Woo sends via JSON a little extra value. I'm checking for a "black" color attribute:

`if( 'black' === strtolower($variation->get_attribute('color')) ){`

But you will want to change to suit your size attribute.

Next, I define the link as

`$kia_data['custom_link'] = sprintf( '<a href="google.com">%s</a>', __( 'Your Link', 'your-textdomain' ) );`

This is just a link to google and so you'll need to change that.

Next, we add an empty `<div>` placeholder. And finally we load some scripts on variable products and listen for the `found_variation` event. When we get it, we get the `variation` from the JSON data and we can check for the `custom_link` we defined earlier and dump it into the empty holder `<div>`.

That's probably clear as mud, but here's the full code snippet:

```
/**
 * Add data to json encoded variation form.
 *
 * @param  array $data - this is the variation's json data
 * @param  object $product
 * @param  object $variation
 * @return array
 */
function kia_available_variation( $data, $product, $variation ){
    if( 'black' === strtolower($variation->get_attribute('color')) ){
        $kia_data['custom_link'] = sprintf( '<a href="google.com">%s</a>', __( 'Your Link', 'your-textdomain' ) );
    } else {
        $kia_data['custom_link'] = false;
    }

    return array_merge( $data, $kia_data );

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'kia_available_variation', 10, 3 );

/**
 * holder for display link
 */
function kia_custom_varition_link() {
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-variation-link"></div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'kia_custom_varition_link', 5 );


/**
 * Add scripts to variable products.
 */
function kia_on_found_template_for_variable_add_to_cart() {
    add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'kia_variable_footer_scripts' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'kia_on_found_template_for_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );


function kia_variable_footer_scripts() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
            $('form.cart')
.on('found_variation', function( event, variation ) {
    if ( variation.custom_link ) {
        $link_html = variation.custom_link;
        $(this).find( '.woocommerce-variation-link' ).html( $link_html ).show();
    } else {
        $(this).find( '.woocommerce-variation-link' ).html('').hide();
    }

 }).on('reset_variation', function( event, variation ) {
    $(this).find( '.woocommerce-variation-link' ).html('').hide();
 });
        });
    </script>
<?php

}
```

Here is the result:
[image: Here is the result showing a Your Link url when the black attribute is selected]

Comment: Thank you Helga. I like this! Been reviewing the code today. Does one always add scripts to wp_print_footer_scripts hook? Also working on figuring out how to hide the link when user selects a different product variation. It currently remains in the woocommerce_single_variation section after it appears.  Also does my solution have any big flaws as well.

Comment: Not always. I was mostly being lazy about not enqueuing a separate .js file. But if you set the footer parameter as true for `wp_enqueue_script()` then `wp_print_footer_scripts` is where it would end up anyway. I've edited the answer to hopefully hide the link for non-relevant variations.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out one way to solve it using  jQuery and  getting the ID of the selection drop down (there were two different ID's named after the attribute slug `#size` & `#pa_size`).

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'add_link_on_selection' );

function add_link_on_selection() {
?>
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#size, #pa_size').change(function(){
    if($('#add').length) {
        $('#add').remove();
        return;

} else {
  $selection = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  console.log($selection);
$(this).after(
  '<div>' +
  ($selection == 'drum' ? '<a href="#"><div id="add">Freight Restrictions</div></a>' : '')  +
  '</div>'
);
}
  })
});
</script>
<?php

}
```